# upgrading port php55 to php56 - conflict with non-existing helpers

Tags: php, port, upgrade, freebsd

I have a freebsd system on which I usually manage ports with portmaster. As php55 was EOL'ed in July 2016, I upgraded php55 to php56 with `portmaster -o /usr/ports/lang/php56 php5-5.5.24`. Worked like a charm.

When updating ports later on (`portmaster -a`), I found that there are PHP helpers like `archivers/php55-bz2` still around. Newer versions (e.g. `archivers/php56-bz2`) cannot be installed because they collide with the old ones and the old ones cannot be removed because the corresponding directories are no longer there.

How do I force-remove the old php55 helpers so I can install the new php56 versions?

Comment: This belongs to ServerFault.

Comment: Does `pkg delete -f` not work for you?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the old port via `pkg_delete` did not work ("package not installed"), with option `-f` only the DB entry was deleted, which still did not permit installation of the new package.

I finally had success deinstalling with `pkg_deinstall`. A half installed new package was uninstalled with `make deinstall` before installation with portmaster succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate from PHP 5.5 to 5.6, you'll have to manually apply `portmaster -o` to all php55-* packages. So, theorically, a command like this may work:

```
awk \
    -vPATTERN="55" \
    -vREPLACEMENT="56" \
    'BEGIN { while (("pkg query -x %o \"/(mod_)?php" PATTERN "(-|$)\"" | getline name) > 0) { oldname = name; sub(PATTERN, REPLACEMENT, name); print "portmaster -o " name " " oldname } }' | sh
```

But this might not be so easy in practice:

- if you were upgrading from 5.X to 7.X, some packages need to be removed first (like pecl-intl or php56-mysql)
- pecl-* packages may also need to be rebuilt (`portmaster pecl`?, if they are compatible - still related to ABI breaks between PHP 5 and 7)

This is why some users prefer to deinstall all old php packages (`pkg delete -R php55\*`) before reinstalling them in a new version.